# Resolving CORS issue in Angular (without access to API)?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following problem:
In my Angular 4 App I want to get (GET Request) data from a public API.

Just calling the URL from Browser or via Postman works perfectly but when I make an HTTP Get request from Angular I get that error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.kraken.com/0/public/AssetPairs.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I found solutions for that but none of them resolved my issue as it is a third party API and not under my control...
I also tried setting headers but it didn't work:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'true' , 'Content-Type':'application/json', 'crossDomain':'true'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: false});
    return this.http.get('https://api.kraken.com/0/public/AssetPairs' , options)
      .map(
        (response: Response) => {
          console.log(response);
          const markets = response.json();
          return markets;
        },
        (error: Error) => {
          console.log('error');
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
```

Thanks in advance for advice!

Comment: CORS protects a servers resources. A client can't bypass that

Comment: @JaromandaX Actually, you can use webpack's proxy to bypass CORS.

Comment: as I said, a **client** can't bypass CORS

Comment: But how could I implement the API then? Isn't it the sense of an API to be usable in third party apps ? lol

Comment: if you don't have access to the server and still want to use the services they expose your only option is to use a proxy you can control

Comment: you will have to set the header of your http response on your server to enable CORS.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use proxy-server. You can access your third part resources though proxy server. For instance you put nginx server and add cors configuration in the nginx.conf. Angular request direct to nginx which then reroute to your third part resources.